# What is the meaning of this subgroup of $S_{n}$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetry

What does the group $H=\left\{\beta \in S_{n} | \beta(1)\in \left\{1,2\right\}, \beta(2)\in\left\{1,2\right\}\right\}$ look like?

Is this the set of permutations that sends position 1 to position 1 or 2, and position 2 to 1 or 2?

I need to show that this is a subgroup of $S_{n}$ but I'm not sure I understand the notation here. I want to use the one-step subgroup test to prove that $H\leq S_{n}$ and to do that I would consider some $\alpha,\beta \in H$ and proceed to show that $\alpha\beta^{-1}\in H$. But if I don't even know what $H$ is, it is hard to show this.

Comment: Do you the decomposition of a permutation as a product of disjoint cycles? B.t.w., this is not a subgroups: identity doesn't have this property by definition.

Comment: So I get that $\beta(1)$ is simply the product of disjoint cycles, but I am unsure what it means by saying $\beta(1)\in\left\{1,2\right\}$. Is it simply saying that $\beta(1)$ maps to 1 or 2?

Comment: This means that in the decomposition of β, there is the transposition τ$_{12}$. β(1) doesn't have a decomposition, since it's not a permutation, but a number.

Comment: But if $\beta \in S_{n}$ doesn't that mean it is a permutation? See, that is what confuses me. You say $\beta(1)$ is a number and when I read it I see $\beta\cdot (1)$. So I'm wrong and it should instead be read as a function?

Comment: If it's β$\cdot (1)$, it's different from β(1). Don't forget a permutation a function which maps $\{1, \dots , n\}$ onto itself.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you know what $H$ is - it is written right there.

- Clearly, the identity is $\in H$
- Let $\beta,\gamma\in H$. As $\beta(1)\in\{1,2\}$ and both $\gamma(1)$ and $\gamma(2)$ are $\in\{1,2\}$, it follows that $\gamma(\beta(1))\in\{1,2\}$. Similarly, $\gamma(\beta(2))\in\{1,2\}$. We conclude that $\gamma\circ\beta\in H$.

As every non-empty and closed under multiplication subset of a finite group is a subgroup, we are done.

---

By the way, for $n\ge 2$, we can readily see that $H\cong S_2\times S_{n-2}$.

Comment: Yes I see $H$ that doesn't mean I necessarily understand it fully.

Comment: @MrStormy83 What I wanted to imply was: For the moment you need only "blindly" apply the possibly confusing definition. Doing so and correspondingly playing around with $H$ may then lead you to full understanding, cf. my closing remark,

Comment: Good clarification, and good advice. I'm starting to get it now.